# Memory leak in program that uses LWP::UserAgent to download a file

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent

I am trying to revive a Perl script I was using a long time ago. It is for downloading files from cloud storage to my local client. I'm pretty sure it worked fine back then, but now I am having the issue that `LWP::UserAgent` downloads the file entirely into the memory before writing it to disk. Expected and former behaviour would be that it should write chunks of the received file to the target during download.

I'm am trying it currently on OSX with Perl 5.16.3 and 5.18 and also tried it on Windows but I do not know the Perl version any more. I am pretty confident that this is related to the Perl version, but I do not know which I used back then and I want to know what changed.

```perl
sub downloadFile {

    my $url           = shift;
    my $filename      = shift;
    my $temp_filename = shift;
    my $expected_size = shift;

    (   $download_size, $received_size, $avg_speed,   $avg_speed_s, $avg_speed_q,
        $speed_count,   $speed,         $byte_offset, $http_status
    ) = ( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 );

    if ( -e $temp_filename and !$options{'no-resume'} ) {

        my @stat = stat($temp_filename);

        if ( $expected_size > $stat[7] ) {
            $byte_offset   = $stat[7];
            $received_size = $stat[7];
        }
    }

    open DOWNLOAD, ( $byte_offset > 0 ) ? ">>" : ">", $temp_filename
            or die "Unable to create download file: $!";
    binmode DOWNLOAD;

    $last_tick = time();

    my $host = "myhost";

    if ( $url =~ m/http:\/\/(.*?)\//gi ) {
        $host = $1;
    }

    $agent->credentials(
            $host . ":80",
            "Login Required",
            $config->{"account_name"},
            $config->{"account_password"} );

    my $response = $agent->get(
            $url,
            ':content_cb'     => \&didReceiveData,
            ':read_size_hint' => ( 2**14 ) );

    close DOWNLOAD;

    my @stat        = stat($temp_filename);
    my $actual_size = $stat[7];

    if ( ! $response->is_success() ) {

        printfvc( 0,
                "\rDownload failed: %s",
                'red',
                $response->status_line() );

        return 0;
    }
    elsif ( $actual_size != $expected_size ) {

        printfvc( 0,
                "\rDownloaded file does not have expected size (%s vs. %s)",
                'red',
                $actual_size, $expected_size );

        return 0;
    }
    else {

        rename $temp_filename, $filename;

        printfvc( 0,
                "\rDownload succeeded                                                           ",
                'green' );

        return 1;
    }
}

sub didReceiveData {

    my ( $data, $cb_response, $protocol ) = @_;

    #my($response, $ua, $h, $data) = @_;
    my $data_size = scalar( length($data) );
    $received_size += $data_size;
    $speed_count   += $data_size;

    my $now = time();

    if ( $last_tick < $now ) {
        $speed       = $speed_count;
        $speed_count = 0;
        $last_tick   = $now;
        $avg_speed_q++;
        $avg_speed_s += $speed;
        $avg_speed = $avg_speed_s / $avg_speed_q;
    }

    if ( $download_size > 0 and $http_status eq "200" or $http_status eq "206" ) {

        print DOWNLOAD $data;

        printf("-> %.1f %% (%s of %s, %s/s) %s      ",
                ( $received_size / $download_size ) * 100,
                fsize($received_size),
                fsize($download_size),
                fsize($speed),
                $avg_speed_q > 3
                ? fduration( ( $download_size - $received_size ) / $avg_speed ) . " remaining"
                : ""
        ) if ( $verbosity >= 0 );
    }
    else {
        printf("-> Initiating transfer...") if ( $verbosity >= 0 );
    }

    return 1;
}
```

**output:**

```
mun-m-sele:PutIO-Perl-folder-sync sele$ perl putiosync.pl 
Syncing folder 'Test' to '/Users/sele/Downloads/Test'...
1 files queued to download
5MB.zip
Fetching '5MB.zip' [1 of 1]

-> 0.3 % (16.0 kiB of 5.0 MiB, 16.0 kiB/s)       
-> 0.6 % (32.0 kiB of 5.0 MiB, 16.0 kiB/s)       
-> 0.9 % (48.0 kiB of 5.0 MiB, 16.0 kiB/s)       
 .
 . 
 .      
-> 99.1 % (5.0 MiB of 5.0 MiB, 16.0 kiB/s)       
-> 99.4 % (5.0 MiB of 5.0 MiB, 16.0 kiB/s)       
-> 99.7 % (5.0 MiB of 5.0 MiB, 16.0 kiB/s)       
Download succeeded
```

So output is as expected **BUT** still this output only appears **after** the file has been loaded into memory.

The `content_cb` is not called during the download (tested by simply putting a `print("cb")` to the top of `didReceiveData`

**update**

I found out that it works as expected on Windows Strawberry Perl 5.16.2. I can provide you with package versions if you tell me which and how ;)

Comment: The Perl is less than ideal but superficially there's nothing wrong with it. `2**14` is `16*1024`, so `LWP` will pass 16KB-ish chunks of data (in memory) to the `didReceiveData` subroutine. It is entirely down to that subroutine what happens thereafter and you don't show it. What makes you think *"it loads it entirely into the memory bevor writing it to the disk"*? There is far to much here that is irrelevant and not enough that is. Please read [*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Borodin you are right of course. I could remove 99% of the code above and reduce it to that one line of code causing my problem. The obvious problem is that I do not know which that would be.
So, while I do not know which line to keep I did add the `didReceiveData` to the code above. And why do I think that it _"it loads it entirely into the memory bevor writing it to the disk"_, well because the memory consumption increases by several GBs before out of a sudden a file at the designated target location with the designated name appears having exactly the same size ;)

Comment: The code has a verbosity setting. Use it to aid debugging the problem, i.e. include the verbose output in your answer.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich $verbosity = 0 is the standard setting which already triggers all print statements in this method. It seems is it not getting called before the download has finished. (the output appears when the file is done)

Comment: @gapvision: "...the output appears when the file is done" - since the output might help in debugging the problem please add it to your question.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich believe me, the output won't help. It just states that the download was successful and tries to print a progress bar

Comment: @gapvision: "... and tries to print a progress bar" - according to your code this indicates that didReceiveData was called, i.e. the content_cb worked. It might of course be a false assumption because it might some progress bar which is outside the code you have shown. Thus having the real output might actually help to verify this assumption. And one could probably also see how often the content_cb was called from this.

Comment: @gapvision: You're rejecting all suggested solutions and requests for more information on the basis that you know better. You won't get help with your problem that way. Is your program really so big that you can't just post all of it? I am sure you would get an answer quickly that way.

Comment: @gapvision: Is this code really your own? Have your really downloaded a file using it?

Comment: @Borodin the code ist originally from https://github.com/arrizer/PutIO-Perl-folder-sync, and I ensure you I downloaded files using it.

Comment: @Borodin so you ask me to post all my code while you are blaming me for posting to much code ?! ;)

Comment: There were too alternatives. The ideal would have been for you to reduce what you posted to a minimal program that still displayed the problems that you needed help with. Failing that, either because you refused or were unable to make that reduction, you could have posted the entire thing in the hope that someone would do it for you. You did neither except for begrudgingly posting the callback subroutine. There has never been a problem either with Perl or with the `LWP` library. Your program has probably never worked properly. Where do you want to go from there?

Comment: If you still have `$agent->add_handler(request_prepare => \&prepareRequest)` and `$agent->add_handler(response_header => \&didReceiveResponse)` from the original `putiosync.pl` then that makes a big difference.

Comment: yes I have, I made no changes to the script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110019/discussion-between-gapvision-and-borodin).

Comment: @gapvision: I'm sorry, I expected that I would be alerted to any posts to the chat room and have only just looked back to check the status of this conversation. I haven't read through thoroughly, but it sounds like you have an answer of some sort? Do let me know if you need anything more

Comment: @Borodin actually not. I only was able to reproduce the version in which is was working as expected => `Windows Strawberry Perl 5.16.2` but I still do not know why it is not working this way anymore...

Comment: @gapvision: Shame we never found a reason for all this but I'm glad to hear it's working for you. Best wishes

Comment: @Borodin well no, its not really working for me. I just could install the working Perl version in a virtual machine, but I am using an mac now, and I fail to assemble the exactly same perl/package versions on this machine... Anyway it would be interesting to know what is wrong (or changed)

Comment: @gapvision: I'm sorry, I thought your *"actually not"* was in response to *"Do let me know if you need anything more"*. I think your best bet is to accumulate what you have discovered and post a new question, with details on which configurations show the problem and which do not. I have no experience with OSX and can't help you there at all

Comment: @Borodin okay seems like a good idea. But Perl version should not differ between operating systems, right? I just mentioned OS X so that to say I can not just simply copy the (working) binaries from the windows machine...

Comment: @gapvision: Any given Perl version may be built with many different configuration parameters, so there's that. But I was thinking more along the lines that the symptoms may be a result of the platform rather than Perl or its modules

Answer (score 2):

Your own code contains a lot of irrelevances, like resume support, multiple server support, progress logging, site credentials, temporary download files, error handling, and average speed calculations. None of these are relevant to the core problem that you described, and that is why I asked you to create a [*Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I don't understand your refusal, or why you seem to be clinging to the idea that the error is in Perl and not in your own code

Without that, all I can do is demonstrate that the technique works well. Here is the sort of thing that you should have generated as a demonstration of the problem. It is very little different from your own code, and it works fine. It downloads an official ISO image of the Ubuntu desktop distribution which is about 1.4GB of information. The process uses a steady 17MB of memory and finishes in 14 minutes. The size of the resultant file exactly matches the `Content-Length` specified in the HTTP header

Beyond this no one can help you further. I encourage you to accept the help of experts when you have asked for it. It's also worth noting that the problem will often be revealed by the process of creating an *MCVE* from your faulty program: you are very likely to delete a non-essential part of the code and find that the issue has disappeared

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use LWP;

use constant ISO_URL => 'http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso';

STDOUT->autoflush;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $expected;
{
    my $res = $ua->head(ISO_URL);
    $expected = $res->header('Content-Length');
    printf "Expected file size is %.3fMB\n",  $expected / 1024**2;
}

my ($iso_file) = ISO_URL =~ m{([^/]+)\z};
open my $iso_fh, '>:raw', $iso_file or die $!;
my $total;
my $pc = 0;

{
    my $res = $ua->get(
        ISO_URL,
        ':content_cb'     => \&content_cb,
        ':read_size_hint' => 16 * 1024,
    );

    close $iso_fh or die $!;

    print $res->status_line, "\n";
    printf "Final file size is %.3fMB\n", (-s $iso_file) / 1024**2;
}

sub content_cb {

    my ( $data, $res ) = @_;

    die $res->status_line unless $res->is_success;

    print $iso_fh $data;

    $total += length $data;
    while ( $pc < 100 * $total / $expected ) {
        printf "%3d%%\n", $pc++;
    }
}
```

#### output

```
Expected file size is 1417.047MB
  0%
  1%
  2%
  3%
  4%
  5%
  :
  :
 95%
 96%
 97%
 98%
 99%
200 OK
Final file size is 1417.047MB
```

Comment: the thing is that I am not saying that you can not download a file using perl/LWP ;) I am saying that the script in my question is not working like excepted. So I do not see the point of writing *another* script that works fine.

Comment: and yes of course I could investigate into the problem by myself, writing MCVEs and trying to put back things together. But I am asking here for help by people who might have already done that and can directly point me to the failure. And just to mention: I do certainly not expect anyone to do this for me if there is no obvious solution for this.

Comment: @gapvision: You are disillusioned. You have a simple bug in your program. There is no conspiracy to prevent you from discovering a change in core Perl that has caused this. See *"you might be right with your evaluation of the http status check"* I *am* right about that, if you have been reliable in posting the actual code that you are running. However I had to revert your first edit which removed a vital part of the first subroutine that copies out the parameter values to lexical variables. That makes me less than confident that even the code that you show is what you're actually running

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the problem is with the file I/O rather than LWP? I assume that data is not being flushed to the file till you close the file.

Below is an example code on how to make File handle flush data to hard disk:

```
{ my $ofh = select LOG;
  $| = 1;
  select $ofh;
}
```

Check out `perldoc -q flush` and this interesting article on buffering, "[Suffering from Buffering?](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html)".

Comment: the thing is, this very script worked perfectly fine on a different perl version.

Comment: @gapvision: It is extremely unlikely that a later release of Perl has caused the problem, as the team go to great lengths to ensure backward-compatability with previous versions--more than for any other language that I know. I also doubt your diagnosis that `LWP` is keeping the downloaded data in memory. The problem is in your code and you're preventing us from helping you to find it

Comment: @Borodin might be, but still extreme unlikely things happen. Something has changed, and just hoped to find someone how can point me to this change

Answer (score 0):

A major problem with your code is that `$http_status` is never assigned. It can be set only by the callback `didReceiveData` or after the entire download has completed when the `get` call exits

But your callback tests whether `$http_status eq "200"` (which should be `$cb_response->is_success`) before printing to the DOWNLOAD file handle, so nothing can ever be written

I can believe that your code escalates memory because it endlessly prints `-> Initiating transfer...` to STDOUT, but nothing will ever be written to the temporary file because of the untested HTTP status. I am certain that you watched your process run and die with an *Out of memory* error and instantly blamed Perl without even trying to download a 1KB file. Your code has never worked, and your question and support of those who would help you is outrageous

*"I'm pretty sure it worked fine back then"* isn't a great start, but when you then reject on that basis all applications of a solution or a request for information then you are being ridiculous

Comment: if I encountered an *Out of memory* error, how comes that it works perfectly fine in terms that the file *is* downloaded and *is* stored into the target file but not chunk-wise but at all at once, once the file is downloaded completely ? So here is my problem with your advice: You don't seem to believe me, neither that this very script worked well before nor that I am able to analyse the execution of the script in terms of seeing that it actually downloads and stores the result into the file. But not in chunks as expected but all at once when its finished

Comment: however I think you might be right with your evaluation of the http status check. I will check on this as soon I am back on my machine

Comment: @gapvision: I don't believe the file is downloaded. Delete the download file and the temporary file and run your program again. I believe your program will exit after some time having filled its memory with thousands of copies of the string `-> Initiating transfer...`. There will be no new file

Comment: what you are saying is simply wrong. Sorry. The file is downloaded complete. There is always a new file. With the correct name. At the correct place. Even with different URLs.

Comment: @gapvision: Unless there is much more to the program than you show, my *"evaluation of the http status check"* would prevent the output file from ever being written. If you're unable to reduce your program to something minimal that still misbehaves then please just post your entire script. Your reluctance to show either your code or your output makes me very suspicious